# I can't figure out why I'm getting a seg fault in my code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I have this

```
void MovieGroup::add(Movie* m)
{
  cout << "Size = " << size << endl;
  if(size < MAX_COLLECTION){

    if(size == 0){
      collection[0] = m;
    }
    else{

      for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){

        if(collection[i]->getYear() >= m->getYear()){

          for(int j = size-1; j != i; j--){
            collection[j] = collection[j-1];
          }
          collection[i] = m;
          break;

        }

        else{
          collection[size] = m;
        }

      }
    }

  size++;

  }
}
```

Everytime I try running it, it gives me a segmentation fault. The purpose of this is to add a movie object to this collection, but sorted by year. I'm really not sure where I'm illegally accessing memory. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Additional info : MAX_COLLECTION is set to 64, I'm trying to start from the back of the array to shift each object over by 1

Comment: Where does the debugger say that the segmentation fault occurs? That may give you a clue. The line `collection[size] = m` looks suspicious.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include a [mre]: a partial definitiono of the `MovieGroup` class, including the constructor and the `collection` and `size` member variables.

Answer (score 1):

The line `collection[size] = m;` is in the wrong place.  It needs to be outside the loop.

Also, when you shift the elements around, you are losing some elements, because you don't shift them all, so you end up overwriting some of them instead.

Also, you should use `return` instead of `break` after you shift the elements, otherwise you would have to keep track of whether the loop does the shift so that code after the loop can act accordingly.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void MovieGroup::add(Movie* m)
{
  cout << "Size = " << size << endl;
  if (size < MAX_COLLECTION) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      if (collection[i]->getYear() >= m->getYear()) {
        for (int j = size-1; j >= i; --j) {
          collection[j+1] = collection[j];
        }
        collection[i] = m;
        ++size;
        return;
      }
    }
    collection[size] = m;
    ++size;
  }
}
```

With that said, I would tweak the function a step further so there is only 1 point of insertion and increment rather than 2 points:

```cpp
void MovieGroup::add(Movie* m)
{
  cout << "Size = " << size << endl;
  if (size < MAX_COLLECTION) {
    int index = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      if (collection[i]->getYear() >= m->getYear()) {
        for (int j = size-1; j >= i; --j) {
          collection[j+1] = collection[j];
        }
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    collection[index] = m;
    ++size;
  }
}
```

And then, I would suggest using standard algorithms instead of manual operations:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void MovieGroup::add(Movie* m)
{
  cout << "Size = " << size << endl;
  if (size < MAX_COLLECTION) {
    auto collection_end = std::next(collection, size);
    auto iter = std::find_if(collection, collection_end,
      [=](Movie *movie){ return movie->getYear() >= m->getYear(); }
    );
    if (iter != collection_end) {
      std::copy_backward(iter, collection_end, collection_end + 1);
    }
    *iter = m;
    ++size;
  }
}
```

And then lastly, you may want to consider changing `collection` to a `std::vector` instead of a fixed-length array, then you can use `std::vector::insert()` and not worry about manually shifting elements or keeping track of the `size`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void MovieGroup::add(Movie* m)
{
  cout << "Size = " << size << endl;
  auto iter = std::find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(),
    [=](Movie *movie){ return movie->getYear() >= m->getYear(); }
  );
  collection.insert(iter, m);
}
```

Comment: This is great! Only thing i'm going to add is size++ right before the return. edit: just refreshed my page and saw you guys already said that lol

Comment: So I added the size++ before return, and it gave me another segfault. But if I remove it, it works, but doesn't keep track of the size properly.

Comment: You have to increment the `size` no matter what, whether you insert `m` into a shifted slot or the end slot